# Lowercase "judaism" on the Ask a Question page

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, user-interface

The "How to Ask" section on the [Ask a Question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page reads (emphasis mine):

> How to Ask
>
> Is your question about **judaism**?
>
> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.
>
> If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

I figure that's the default.  Can we change it?

Comment: FTR christianity is not capitalized but Islam is.

Comment: FTFR (for the further record), ["Android"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), ["Apple"](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), ["Mathematica"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), ["Linux"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), ["English"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), ["English" again](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and ["Drupal"](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) are capitalized. ["WordPress"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) is written thus. I didn't check any of the other sites.

Comment: This has now been fixed.

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Should I make a meta post like this on C.SE to request the same change?

Comment: @JarrodDixon, thank you! You may want to fix [Christianity's](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) while you're at it. `:-)`

Comment: @msh210 good idea; fixed, as well.

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Yay! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to close the loop: this has been resolved.